# Match until the next (and not the last) space after a specific pattern

Tags: .net, regex

Considering the following string

```
"Nr.: &N|1|2|3|4|5|6|7 / 8|9|10|11|12 / 2014"
```

I would like to get the following match:

```
"&N|1|2|3|4|5|6|7 / 8|9|10|11|12 "
```

Though the regex pattern `&N\|(.*|$)\s` matches:

```
"&N|1|2|3|4|5|6|7 / 8|9|10|11|12 / "
```

But after the last vertical line, I would like to match only until the **next** and not the **last** space.

Any ideas of how I could solve this?

Comment: There are many ways to match it, including `&[^/]*/[^/]*`. But how strict do you want the regex to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this. My personal creation:

`&.*\|[^ ]*`

Comment: after editing to &N.*\|[^ ]*, it fits perfectly my criteria, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

One of many ways you could achieve this.

```
&[^&]*(?=/)
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/aB2rV9)

Comment: I can't rely on the slash, so Vasili's answer did it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

If there is always going to be a space and a slash and a space and a year at the end you can do this:

```
&N\|(.*|$)\/
```

The match will be:

```
"1|2|3|4|5|6|7 / 8|9|10|11|12 "
```

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/tU8bC3)

Comment: I can't rely on the slash, so Vasili's answer did it. Thanks anyway!