# How to get match until the last character that is not space

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
aa              
bb cc           
dd              
ee ff gg
```

*Notice to the spaces:
[image]

I want to get match on every line until the last character that is not space.
This is what I want:

```
aa
bb cc
dd
ee ff gg
```

It looks like that:
[image]

I tried to follow:
[Match until the next (and not the last) space after a specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135897/match-until-the-next-and-not-the-last-space-after-a-specific-pattern)

And use:

```
.* [^ ]*
```

But it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do it:

```
.*([^\s]+)
```

Reference:
[regular expression: match any word until first space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400431/regular-expression-match-any-word-until-first-space)